# Is there any way to update all collections at once firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Currently I'm having a scenario where I need to update every single document of every collection that exists in my firestore.
All I want to update all documents in all collections whenever there's any update in a specified collection.
What I have seen so far is the updates of document in a single collection only.

```
 db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.ref.update({
            capital: true
        });
    });
});
```

This is what I can do for a single collection.
Furthermore I have a generic trigger than monitors all the collections create/update/delete with wildcard of '{collectionId}/{documentId}'

```
functions
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540, memory: '2GB' })
  .firestore.document(`{collectionId}/{documentId}`)
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {...}
```

Comment: There's an excellent answer by @frankvanpuffelen, which should be accepted but I would be curious what use case creates a situation where every document of every collection needs to be updated. That's a lot of writing of data (and very costly). It really sounds more like a database structure issue that may be resolved through the use of references to data in other collections - possibly undenormalization (e.g. normalize the data)? Probably too in depth to be discussed in comments but just throwing it out there for consideration.

Comment: @Jay Yeah there's an issue with database structure which needs to be changed in later future but for now we need to stick with the same structure and continue with any method that works for it.

Comment: Great question Jay, and thanks for elaborating Waseem. I had indeed assumed it was a database migration/backfill scenario. Where possible I'd prefer an on-demand backfill/migration, but those are hard to then ever consider complete (since you typically can't query on documents that don't have the new fields). Very interesting topic, but... hard to squeeze in comments indeed. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in operation for updating all documents in all collections. But since you're running in Cloud Functions already, you can use the Node.js Admin SDK to [list all collections](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections), loop over them and then update all documents in each of them.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try this approach and will see what I can get the maximum from it.