# Flutter cloud-function: Schedule function for multiple collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to use one `CloudFunction` to schedule time in multiple collections but with the same field name? If yes, how do I do that?

For instance I have different types of collections called ADS. That is `ADS1`, `ADS2` `ADS3`... But each of these ads have a field with the same name - `"TimestampDeparture"`. Can I create only one function to update all the fields in all the collections or I have to create a function seperately for each?
If one function can do for all, how do I do that?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduled = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun(async (context) => {
  const batch = database.batch()
  const {docs} = await database.collection("ADS").get() ///so maybe is there a way I can list the collection? Or is there any other way?
  docs.map(doc => {
    const {
      TimestampDeparture,
      Status
    } = doc.data()
    const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
    const higger = now > TimestampDeparture

    batch.set(
      database.doc(`ADS/${doc.id}`),{
         updateTime: higger? TimestampDeparture : now,
         Status: higger? 'COMPLETED' : Status
      }, {
        merge: true
      }
    )
  })

  await batch.commit()
})
```

Comment: Just write a loop and do the same thing foreach of the ADS you want to process? Or are you asking how to list collection names in Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to update specific fields in the document of the following collections. ADS1, ADS2, ADS3….. But you are using cloud Pubsub to schedule this job infinitely. This function will run infinitely thus exhausting your quota.

Alternatively you can use [Firebase-Function OnRequest trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd)  to retrieve all the documents and update the same using batch. You can check some similar code snippet in this [Stackoverflow Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484348/18265702) and [Stackoverflow Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74880771/18265702).

Have a look at below example code for better understanding.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Run this function just once
exports.examplefunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const collectionNames = ['ADS1', 'ADS2', /* ... */ ];
    const dataToUpdate = {
        field1: 'newValue1',
        field2: 'newValue2',
        /* fields to be updated */
    };

    collectionNames.forEach(collectionName => {
        admin.firestore()
            .collection(collectionName)
            // Query for documents to update (if needed):
            .where('field', '==', value) // Example query
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    doc.ref.update(dataToUpdate);
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error updating documents:', error);
            });
    });
});
```

**#Update**:

To answer your recent comment `For example, where I have database.collection("ADS"), is it possible to add other collections this collections such as database.collection(["ADS1", "ADS2", "ADS3"])? Or I have to create a function for each of them?` As Frank van Puffelen suggested in this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109817/18265702) it seems

> There's no built-in operation for updating all documents in all collections. But since you're running in Cloud Functions already, you can use the Node.js Admin SDK to [list all collections](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections), loop over them and then update all documents in each of them.

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't think you got the question right. To update a field of a document in one collection is easy. But here is the I've created mutilple collections. All these collections have fields with the same name (say "Timestamp"). Collection ADS1 has a document with the field "Timestamp", likewise collection ADS2 and ADS3. I want to create only function that applies to all the collections. That's what I want to know if it's possible and how to do it

Comment: For example, where I have database.collection("ADS"), is it possible to add other collections this collections such as database.collection(["ADS1", "ADS2", "ADS3"])? Or I have to create a function for each of them?

Comment: @EbenOasis  I have updated my answer based upon your recent reply. Let me know if the suggestions helped? or you are looking for something else?